# How to request a secured connection (https)?

Tags: android

Generally, we use http connection like this:

```
try{

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
//              final HttpParams params = httpclient.getParams();
//              HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT);
//              HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, WAIT_TIMEOUT);
//              ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, WAIT_TIMEOUT);

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

        }catch(Exception e){
              // Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
```

This code snippet is used for http.

How can I request a secured connection (https) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are after Android 2.2, you can simply use class [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html).
It will be work through https, if url scheme is https.

Otherwise, you can look to [its source](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch?q=package%3aandroid.git.kernel.org%20file%3aandroid/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.java) and make similar, and may be even easier.

Comment: I am already using httpclient here, I want to know if some other secured way is available or not.

Comment: when i try to use AndroidHttpClient() i am getting this error - The constructor AndroidHttpClient() is not visible

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy use `newInstance()`.